# How to call from Global.asax a method that is in a page's codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

I have an ASP.NET project that contains several pages. In one of the pages' code behind, for example i have a CheckSecurity() function. I want to call this method from Global.asax. I want to use this CheckSecurity() method in Session_Start().

Is it possible to call a method like that from Global.asax Session_Start() ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not put the method in a shared code file and call it from anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `class`, put the `CheckSecurity()` method in that class and call the method within the `Global.asax` `Session_Start()` method or any other `page`.

Comment: Actually, the method i want to call is in another application, in my website there are two application. One of them is a .net 1.1 app, and the other one is .net 3.5 app. I want to call a method from .net 3.5 app in .net 1.1 app.

Comment: I don't think you can add a reference to a .NET 3.5 project in a lesser version of the framework, look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557987/why-does-adding-a-reference-to-project-targeting-net-framework-4-0-fail. But then again just try creating a class in the 3.5 project, add a reference of the project to the 1.1 project and see what happens.

Comment: @ErdemGundogdu You can't do that. You should create a new dll moving the needed 1.1 functionality in a library that can be used by the .net 3.5 app.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a page method static and can call it from global.asax Session_Start() just go through the link [Call function in aspx.cs page from global.asax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319154/call-function-in-aspx-cs-page-from-global-asax)

Comment: There's another issue with calling the method via different projects and different .net versions to.